# How to get the username in the accounts-github package

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I have one user in my app (myself) and am using the `accounts-github` package.

When I run `Meteor.users.find({}).fetch()` I see this:

```
[ { _id: 'fX7DZvFAe6KC9QvE8',
    services: { resume: [Object] },
    status: { online: true, lastLogin: [Object], idle: false } } ]
```

It would be great if this included a username. Anyone know how this is possible?

Comment: Can you please share the values in resume inside services ?

Comment: @PankajJatav oh my bad I already figured it out but forgot to add an answer here. Will do so now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that elsewhere in my application I called `Accounts.onCreateUser` which *overwrites* the default function, part of which is setting the profile on the user.

To fix this, I added the following to my `onCreateUser`:

```
Object.assign user,
  profile: options.profile || {}
```

See the comments here as well: https://github.com/meteor/docs/issues/81